# Executar uma função GCM antes de desinstalar app

Tags: android

Estou com uma aplicação Android que está usando GCM, queria saber como funciona o método unRegistered, como eu posso fazer, para que quando o usuario desinstale a aplicação ele automáticamente saia do meu GCM e também gostaria de tirar do meu banco de dados o id dele, coisa que já acho mais complexo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não existe nenhuma `Intent`/`Receiver` ou "callback" que seu aplicativo possa notificado de sua própria desinstalação.

Existe um `Broadcast` de `ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED`<sup>1</sup>, que é disparado para todos os `receivers` que estão registrados para esse `Intent`, mas o seu aplicativo não é notificado<sup>2</sup> se eles estiver sendo desinstalado.

O GCM possui uma forma de detecção, e é baseada no status `NotRegistered` da resposta de um envio de mensagem ao servidor GCM.

Esse é o único indicativo de que o aplicativo foi desinstalado e não esta mais disponível a receber mensagens. Os passos são os seguintes<sup>3</sup>:

- O usuário desinstala seu aplicativo.
- O seu servidor tenta enviar uma mensagem para o servidor GCM, como alvo o seu aplicativo que foi desinstalado em um determinado dispositivo.
- O GCM envia a mensagem para o dispositivo.
- O Cliente GCM do dispositivo recebe a mensagem, **consulta o `PackageManager`** verificando se tem um `BroadcastReceiver` configurado para aceitar essa mensagem, **retornando falso** para o aplicativo que foi desinstalado.
- O Cliente GCM notifica ao servidor GCM que a aplicação foi desinstalada. E o servidor GCM marca aquele `registration_id` para deleção.
- Seu servidor tentar enviar uma nova mensagem para o mesmo aplicativo/dispositivo.
- O Servidor GCM responderá ao seu servidor com um erro de `NotRegistered` para tal mensagem.
- Seu servidor remove o `registration_id` do banco.

**Essa é a única forma usando GCM de detectar a desinstalação.**

Dê uma olhada nos tipo de status da resposta HTTP, mais especificamente no campo `failure` e no campo `error` de cada `registration_id` (que houve falha), ele vem com o valor `NotRegistered`, que o GCM pode enviar de acordo com a [documentação](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html).

**Referências**

1. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_REMOVED
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6209730/is-it-possible-to-detect-android-app-uninstall
3. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html#unreg